# LinguaPlone 4.1.1 not translating page/object content

Tags: plone, linguaplone

Thanks Stack =)

## **Expected Outcome:**

Successful translation of existing website pages into Spanish

## **Actual Outcome:**

Page title, description, and content is not translated.

## **Stack:**

- Ubuntu  Ubuntu 10.04.4 LT (Lucid)
- Apache 2.2.14
- Plone-4.1.4-UnifiedInstaller
- LinguaPlone 4.1.1

## **Troubleshooting**

**zmi/portal_languages has the following settings:**

- Use the language of the content item.
- Use cookie for manual override. (Required for the language selector
  viewlet to be rendered.)
- Use browser language request negotiation.
- Create content initially as neutral language.

**Used mysite.org/@@language-setup-folders to establish language folders**

- Language folders en and es created successfully

**When i select "Translate into: Spanish"**

- I choose a page to translate, in example "Apprenticeship".
- My edit url looks like this: mysite.com/apprenticeship-es/edit
- I am presented with my original untranslated text and a form.
  Ironically all the plone menus and form components translate perfectly
  but my content remains untranslated.

I tried coping and pasting the text into the form thinking maybe it would translate it but after i save the page: apprentiship-es, its contents still render in English. I tried copying it into mywebsite.com/es directory but that had no affect either.

Comment: Please clarify: is your problem that your text is not magically transformed into another language by automatic means or is your problem that elements of the user interface show in an unsuitable language? The former is not a bug, you'll have to provide the Spanish equivalent of your English content.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz. To clarify i thought linguaplone would translate my content. For example if i create a page in english called apprenticeships i thought linguaplone would translate it into Spanish. Is this not the case? From your comments it seems linguaplone only translate the Plone UI and i will have to use an external translator like babelfish to convert my Enlish pages to their Spanish equivalent?

Comment: LinguaPlone does not actually translate the text for you. It just provides the framework in which you can provided different translations of pages that are automatically presented to users that have a certain language selected for their browser. If you want something that will translate for you automatically, just use http://translate.google.com/translate_tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
My question was irrelevant to linguaplone since it doesn´t perform "User Created" content translation. It translates plones user interface and give us a nice form to paste our translated text into. As @vangheem said, a translation framework.

If you want to translate your "User created" content ie webpages use an external service like:

- translate.google.com/translate_tools
- http://www.babelfish.com/

Comment: IMHO real translations can only be done by humans, knowing both cultures. even then there's a lot of different ways to do it. try to translate shakespeare... it's just not possible to describe it fully in a mathematical way.